# Random partial classical Hilbert style calculus decidable?

Tags: propositional-calculus, decidability

The language is only {->}. Assume we have a random set of propositional axiom schemas A1,..,An. We even know that each Aj is generally valid in classical logic. But we don't know whether we have a complete set of

axiom schemas for classical logic. Besides the axiom schemas we also have the modus ponens rule A, A -> B / B. Is such a Hilbert style calculus decidable. Is there an algorithm given a propositional formula C, that can nevertheless decide whether

C is derivable or not. It might not derive all classical propositional theorems, but can we arrange that some proof search always terminates with either the answer "yes", C is derivable or "no", C is not derivable?

Comment: I do not know of any undecidable implicational fragments of classical propositional logic. What I know is that the decidability of the implicational fragment of relevance logic $R$ was open for some years before it was eventually established by Kripke (1959), and later Urquhart (1990) showed that the problem is intrinsically hard - every decision procedure for it requires exponential space in the input. Therefore you should not expect a simple *positive* answer to your question.

Comment: Or the answer is negative, was having a look at Undecidable problems for propositional calculi with implication
Grigoriy V. Bokov, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00978.pdf

Comment: You might want to consider posting this as an answer then!

Comment: I do not yet understand the paper. I am still hoping for a positive answer. Still digging around what is known about the problem.